# Can not pass jsp value to javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am working on a `jsp` application. I have a bean user. In `javascript` I have the user id.
I want to send it to `javascript`. With the getter method of id - `getId()` I have tried the
following thing but it not working -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userId = '<% getId()%>';
    alert("User Id is: " + userId);
</script>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Can any one help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `'<% %>'`. You have to use `"<%= %>"`. Your code be written as -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userId = "<%=getId()%>";
    alert("User Id is: " + userId);
</script>
```

I think this should solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Its not recommended to use JSP Scriptlets, Set User Id in session and access that in JSP using [EL expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("User Id is: " + ${userId});
</script>
```